# gerunds as a nouns

Tags: grammar, nouns, gerunds

I can't understand why in examples beneath parts 'paying attention' and 'accepting payments' go without ***the + of***.

1) **I have friends who pride themselves in paying attention to detail.**
Maybe it is an adjective clause? (Like this: *They write letters paying attention to detail*.)

If I say ''**the paying of attention** to detail is important'' - it works as a large noun phrase. We use article+gerund+of+noun.

2) **How do you go about accepting payments for clients?** - the same thing. An adjective clause? If not, why does it go without an article+of? *The king of the road; knight of a horde* and so on.

3) **How do you go about *the* acceptance *of* payments for clients?** - a large noun phrase.

4) ***The* accepting *of* payments is an important part of our business plan?** It works.
But **How do you go about the accepting of payments for clients?** doesn't.

5) **The skillful defusing of the bomb saved the day**. Here we have the gerund packaged inside a prepositional phrase 'defusing of the bomb'
**Aardvark’s quickly defusing the bomb saved the day** - ...defusing the bomb...without OF...Why on earth does it go without of?

Comment: 1) and 2) don't require a determiner because they are verbs, not nouns. "Defusing" is also a verb in your last example, where it has "the bomb" as direct object. It would be a noun in "Aardvark’s quick defusing of the bomb saved the day", with adjectival "quick" and an _of_ PP complement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference arises from whether the '-ing' word is a true noun gerund, or a verb present participle.

> The **paying of attention** is important.

'The paying' is a gerund/noun.

> **Paying attention** is important.

Paying is a verb/present participle.

> Aardvark's quick **defusing of the bomb** saved the day.

"Defusing" is a noun/gerund.

> Quickly **defusing the bomb**, Aardvark saved the day.

"Defusing" is a verb/present participle.

If you have trouble telling if an '-ing' word is a participle or a gerund, try replacing it with a word you know is definitely a noun or verb to see if that clarifies the problem for you. If it can be replaced by a noun without '-ing' and still make sense, it is a gerund.

> Aardvark's quick **action (noun)** saved the day.
>
> **Action (noun)** is important.

Comment: 'he had witnessed the killing of the birds' - nouny gerund  
'he was expelled for killing the birds' - verby gerund

English is quirky

Comment: @ThroughTheWonders "Killing" is noun in your first example, and a verb in the second. Noun status is evident fom "the", and the _of_ PP complement. Verb status is clear from the direct object "the birds".

Comment: yes, I have somehow managed to get it. Thank you, guys!